# How to create DataFrame from Scala's List of Iterables?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Scala value:

```
val values: List[Iterable[Any]] = Traces().evaluate(features).toList
```

and I want to convert it to a DataFrame.

When I try the following:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(values)
```

I got this error:

```
error: overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives:

[A <: Product](data: Seq[A])(implicit evidence$2: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame 
[A <: Product](rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[A])(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
cannot be applied to (List[Iterable[Any]])
          sqlContext.createDataFrame(values)
```

Why?

Comment: `List[Iterable[Any]]`? You don't. If values can be expressed using SQL types convert to `List[Row]` and provide schema.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As [zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323) mentioned, we need to first convert `List[Iterable[Any]]` to `List[Row]` and then put rows in `RDD` and prepare schema for the spark data frame.

To convert `List[Iterable[Any]]` to `List[Row]`, we can say

```
val rows = values.map{x => Row(x:_*)}
```

and then having schema like `schema`, we can make RDD

```
val rdd = sparkContext.makeRDD[RDD](rows)
```

and finally create a spark data frame

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

Comment: I guess you meants `sparkContext.makeRDD[Row](rows)` ?

Comment: `makeRDD[Row]` would get error,  `val rdd = sparkContext.makeRDD(rows)` is fine for me.

Answer (score 48):

Thats what spark implicits object is for. It allows you to convert your common scala collection types into DataFrame / DataSet / RDD. 
Here is an example with Spark 2.0 but it exists in older versions too

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val values = List(1,2,3,4,5)

val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val df = values.toDF()
```

Edit: Just realised you were after 2d list. Here is something I tried on spark-shell. I converted a 2d List to List of Tuples and used implicit conversion to DataFrame:

```
val values = List(List("1", "One") ,List("2", "Two") ,List("3", "Three"),List("4","4")).map(x =>(x(0), x(1)))
import spark.implicits._
val df = values.toDF
```

Edit2: The original question by MTT was How to create spark dataframe from a scala list for a 2d list for which this is a correct answer. The original question is https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38063195/1 
The question was later changed to match an accepted answer. Adding this edit so that if someone else looking for something similar to the original question can find it.

Comment: Good Answer, I didn't knew that it was possible to convert a list to a dataframe directly (I thought that we should create an RDD first). 
This can be very helpful in unit tests. +1

Comment: How would you modify this for heterogeneous column types, i.e. for List(List(1, "One") ,List(2, "Two") ,List(3, "Three"),List(4,"Four"))?

Comment: @SarahMesser You'd be better off starting with a List of tuples rather than with a List of Lists. Alternatively and less elegantly when you convert your List of Lists to list of tuples, you can cast each element of the tuple to a type e.g. `.map(x =>(x(0).asInstanceOf[Int], x(1).asInstanceOf[String]))` 
When the type is `scala.Any`, spark cannot know what column type should it be converted to

Comment: The question is clearly different.

Answer (score 13):

Simplest approach:

```
val newList = yourList.map(Tuple1(_))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(newList).toDF("stuff")
```

Answer (score 2):

In Spark 2 we can use DataSet by just converting list to DS by toDS API

```
val ds = list.flatMap(_.split(",")).toDS() // Records split by comma
```

or

```
val ds = list.toDS()
```

This more convenient than `rdd` or `df`

Comment: toDF() does not operate on List[List[Any]]

Answer (score 2):

The most concise way I've found:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(List("A", "B", "C").map(Tuple1(_)))
```

Comment: This worked for me! For map to DF.. `spark.createDataFrame(myMap.toList.map(e => Tuple2(e._1, e._2))).toDF("col1", "col1")`