# Spark: Dataframe "except" method raises error: "unresolved operator: 'Except;"

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a couple of DataFrame objects, called (say) `df1` and `df2`, and am trying to find the rows that are in `df1` but not `df2`.  The [except](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#except(org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)) method seems like just what I need, but when I call it, I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: unresolved operator 'Except;
```

From searching around it seems that this error can (or used to be) raised if the DataFrames don't have the same structure, but when I print out their textual representations, they look identical:

```
[user_id: int, doc_days: map<int,smallint>, updated_at: string]
```

I've experimented on the REPL, manually creating DataFrames that have the same structure as that, and `except` works as expected with them.

Why mightn't `except` work on my "real" data?

Comment: Sounds like incorect version of Spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out it's the `map` column that's the culprit.  I had been creating my DataFrame using the `parallelize` method, eg:

```
val df = spark.parallelize(Seq((1, Map(1 -> 2.toShort), "foo")))
```

The `except` method works fine if I omit the Map from this data, and the code doesn't even compile if I try to parallelize a Seq of Maps.

I eventually found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063195/how-to-create-dataframe-from-scalas-list-of-iterables) which suggested an alternate approach:

```
val schema = StructType(
  Seq(
    StructField("user_id", IntegerType),
    StructField("doc_days", MapType(IntegerType, ShortType)),
    StructField("updated_at", StringType)
  )
)

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sparkContext.makeRDD(data), schema)
```

...where `data` is the `Seq` from above.

When I do it this way, `except` works as expected in all cases.