# randomly initialized dataframe in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, for-loop, functional-programming, apache-spark-sql

I need to create a dataframe with n rows, and each column value of a row initialized with 0/1 randomly. An example dataframe would be:

```
+----+----+----+
| id | c1 | c2 |
+----+----+----+
|  1 |  0 |  1 |
|  2 |  1 |  1 |
|  3 |  1 |  0 |
+----+----+----+
```

Currently I am using following procedure:

- create empty dataframe
- generate individual sequence
- append to existing dataframe using union()

The code is as follows:

```
for (k <- 0 until n) { 
  var newRow = k+:Seq.fill(N)(Random.nextInt(2)) // random fill with 0/1 and appending id
  X = X.union(newRow.toDF())
}
```

Does above method hurt performance(running time)? Is there any better way to  do this?

Comment: Union is expensive. You could create a list and then convert the list to dataframe (sorry, not a Scala expert :( )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an implicit method that creates `DataFrame` from `Iterable` in scala, you can make use of that provided, that it consists of tuples. The following code:

```
val a = (for (_ <- 0 until 5) yield Seq.fill(3)(Random.nextInt(2)))
    .map(x => (x(0), x(1), x(2)))
import spark.implicits._
a.toDF.show
```

Gives the following result:

```
+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  1|
|  1|  0|  0|
|  0|  0|  0|
|  0|  1|  0|
|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

You can provide a schema / rename the columns properly. More information on why those innner-structures have to be tuples can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182950/7606764).

Comment: let's say the iterable to be converted is too large to be stored in the driver program. Is there any other method to create dataframe ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does above method hurt performance(running time)?

In a quite a few ways, but primarily as a result of growing lineage and execution plan. Additionally calling `toDF` on a local sequence will keep all data in memory of the driver.

In other words - it doesn't scale at all.

> Is there any better way to do this?

Of course there is:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand

spark.range(n).select(
  $"id" + 1 as "id", 
  (rand() > 0.5) cast("integer") as "c1", (rand() > 0.5) cast("integer") as "c2")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is what I wanted, but I needed it be generalized for variable number of columns (let's say x columns with names _c1 to _cx). How can we deal with this requirement ?