# In Scala, define a generic tuple type with variable length and multiple types

Tags: scala, generics, types, tuples, scala-2.12

How can I define a generic tuple type that can

- have variable length
- contain different types

?

In the below example, I would need to define the return type of `foo` in `trait A` to match the implementations of the children objects.

```scala
trait A {
  def foo: // how to define the return type here?
}

object O1 extends A {
  def foo: (Int, String) = (123, "a string")
}

object O2 extends A {
  def foo: ((String, Boolean), Int) = (("string inside a sub-tuple", true), 0, "another string")
}
```

Comment: Is this **Scala 2** or **Scala 3**? Also, note that this kind of types are usually hard to use so make sure this is really what you want.

Comment: This is **Scala 2**. This is the only option I have found for now but will continue to explore.

Comment: I think, SO "close" menu needs to have a button for the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) :). Show an example of how you are going to _use_ this type if you were able to define it. Like `def x(a: A) = { val foo = a.foo ..` _Then_ what? What do expect to do with it that you could not do with `Seq[Any]`?

Comment: I want to use this as a parameter of Spark's createDataFrame function, which parameter type is defined as `createDataFrame[A <: Product : TypeTag](data: Seq[A])`. I would convert the Tuple to Seq and use it like: `spark.createDataFrame(Seq(O1.foo))`. createDataFrame does not accept `Seq[Any]`. If I can define the same generic type I look for but for Seq, that would fit my needs. Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: Interesting XY problem. This is my first question here after years of reading only, I'll think through that!

Comment: Tuples are already a generic type in Scala with variable arguments and multiple types. There's `Tuple2[T1,T2]`,  `Tuple3[T1,T2,T3]` and so on until `Tuple22`. If `createDataFrame` is what you are needing this for, this can answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063195/how-to-create-dataframe-from-scalas-list-of-iterables

Comment: @pierre-vr Well, you can use `O1.foo` as it is ... But what is the use of `A` (the trait, not type parameter). What is the utility of having O1 extend it?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is **Scala 2** you have two options.

### 1. Vanilla Scala

Using only vanilla **Scala**, you can do this:

```scala
trait A {
  type O <: Product
  def foo: O
}

object O1 extends A {
  override final type O = (Int, String)

  override def foo: (Int, String) =
    (123, "a string")
}
```

This may work if you never want to abstract over `A`, but if you do then using `Product` is extremely unpleasant.

### 2. Shapeless

If you use [**Shapeless**](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) which means you may use `HList` instead of `Product`, that would make harder the use of a concrete implementation but easier an abstract usage *(but still pretty unpleasant)*.

---

Anyways, I still recommend you to check if this is really the best solution to your meta-problem.

Comment: " if you do then using Product is extremely unpleasant" ... and if you don't then you don't need `A` do begin with :D